# Leibniz rule or not? improper integral?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

If
$f(x)=(\int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt)^2$ and $g(x)$=$\int_0^1{e^{-x^2(1+t^2)}\over(1+t^2)}dt$ then $f'(\sqrt\pi) + g'(\sqrt\pi)$ is equal to??
i tried to use Leibniz rule and differentiate with respect to x but got got stuck in between could someone help me

Comment: The first just follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus. The second is almost trivial if you evaluate the integral first. Hint: ${1+t^2 \over 1+t^2} = 1$.